# User entries not updating in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using postman to send a request and I see Success message but in the database, it's not updated at all. 

PostMAN request
[image: PostMan request]

database Snap shot
[image]

update services object: from this file I have used a database query to insert data in the database and set callBack funtion

```
const pool = require('../../config/database')

module.exports = {
updateUser: (data, callBack) => {
    pool.query(
      `UPDATE users SET firstName=?,email=?,password=?,lastName=?,phoneNumber=?, sex=? WHERE id=?`, [
        data.firstName,
        data.email,
        data.password,
        data.lastName,
        data.phoneNumber,
        data.sex,
        data.id
      ], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          return callBack(error)
        }
        return callBack(null, results)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

update user controller here I have added a controller to update the user details which receive the data from update user services.

```
const {
   create,
   getUserbyID,
   getUsers,
   updateUser,
   deleteUser,
   getUserByEmail
 } = require('./userService')
const {genSaltSync, hashSync, compareSync} = require('bcrypt')
const { sign } = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports ={
updateUser: (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const salt = genSaltSync(10);
    body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
    updateUser(body, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return false;
      } // added
      console.log("this is the body: "+JSON.stringify(req.body))
      console.log("this is the results: "+ JSON.stringify(results))
      if (!results) {
        return res.json({
          success:0,
          message: "failed to update user"
        })
      }
      return res.json({
        success: 1,
        message: "Updated Sucessfully"
      })
    })
  },
}
```

router.js

```
router.patch('/update',checkToken, updateUser)
```

**ADDED** console.log

```
this is the body: {"Id":15,"firstName":"joey","email":"joey.chandler357@gmail.com","password":"$2b$10$ZBnRppSKAfQ1TrzGvs/wqOrVx/shb6ESJ7emXnC7IlWRN3VUGgfK2","lastName":"chandler","phoneNumber":"9860316634","sex":"Male"}
this is the results: {"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
```

Comment: Are you sure you should use "update" instead of "insert" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your console.log message

```
this is the results: {"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
```

Here you can notice affectedRows: 0 it means no row updated this happens when condition is not matched with any of the records. In postman you are passing "Id" I is in capital format but at the time of accessing this in service you are using "data.id" id is small latter so this is creating problem

we can handle this
instead of
if (!results) {
return res.json({
success:0,
message: "failed to update user"
})
}
use

```
if (!results.affectedRows) {
    return res.json({
      success:0,
      message: "failed to update user"
    })
  }
```

this will be much better then previous check

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an "insert" to add the db record. It's using an update... so it's looking for a pre-existing record.

Comment: I am doing update of pre-existing record how can I use insert to update the data

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

1. wrap “users” in quotes on your update query. I’ve seen this w Postgres where some words are reserved in raw queries.
2. Examine the database response from your update. See what is console logged.

Comment: the result from the database is undefined

Comment: Id passed was 15 on the body. Is there a record w that Id? Also, you have Id capitalized on the body, but then you’re using it as “data.id”. Make sure it’s same case. When in doubt, enable logging on your db client. See what query is actually being sent to the db.